# Executing error.... "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

```
private void btnFinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvProducts.RowCount == 0)
    {
        DataAccess.InformUser("Please add some product to the Sale....");
        return;
    }

    int intTotalSaleAmount = int.Parse(lblTotalSaleAmount.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);

    string saleId;
    saleId = Sales.Add(txtCustomerId.Text, dtpSaleDate.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy"), txtDescription.Text, intTotalSaleAmount.ToString());

    // now add all the sale details....


    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvProducts.Rows)
    {
        string productId = Products.SelectByProductName("ProductId", dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString())[0].ToString();
        string quantity = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string unitPrice = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        Sales.AddDetails(saleId, productId, quantity, unitPrice);
    }

    DataAccess.InformUser("The sale has been finalized....");
    dgvProducts.Rows.Clear();
    cmbProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
    lblTotalSaleAmount.Text = "0";
}
```

I'm making a software in C# using visual studio 2010. Everything is OK before executing the program but when I click on the Finalize Button, it shows me the specified error:

> Input string was not in correct format

I'm sure that the error is in following line:

```
int intTotalSaleAmount = int.Parse(lblTotalSaleAmount.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: What is the value of `lblTotalSaleAmount.Text` exactly and what `Culture` you are using?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your text is not always formatted correctly, use :

```
int intTotalSaleAmount = 0;

if (int.TryParse(lblTotalSaleAmount.Text, out intTotalSaleAmount))
{
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Although this is a solution to the exception it is not a solution to the real problem.

Comment: Side note - you don't need to initialize `out` variable.